# Disable PHP script execution limit

Tags: php, limit, execution

`set_time_limit(0)` will reset the counter to 0, but I would need to call it like every 30 seconds or so in order for the script to continue running without breaking in error.

Is there any way I could just disable this time limit stuff, without having to call this function repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the limit to 0 disables it entirely. Setting it to non-zero resets the countdown to that value. e.g.

```
while(true) {
   set_time_limit(30);
   sleep(29);
}
```

Will run (virtually) indefinitely, because the limit keeps getting reset to 30, one second before it was about to expire.

Comment: oh so setting it to 0 disables it? Idk why I read somewhere on SO that you have to call this function multiple times..

Comment: Only if you're using a non-zero value. Once at zero, it's disabled, as explicitly stated in the docs: http://php.net/set_time_limit

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to call `set_time_limit(0)` once, unless you are running PHP in safe-mode which a lot of shared web hosts do

Read the docs for `set_time_limit()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)